# PlatformNotSupportedException with NAudio WaveOut in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, naudio

I am trying to play sounds on a secondary soundcard using `NAudio` in a `Unity` project.
**It works successfuly** using the `Play` button in the editor, but **not in the executable build**.

Here is the error i get :

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
          at System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in <0b0c181c86c84da989ad80998d3a0a84>:0 
          at NAudio.Wave.WaveWindow.OnMdiChildActivate (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <554b80148c284b99953f098db496ebd4>:0 
          at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) NAudio.Wave.WaveWindow..ctor(NAudio.Wave.WaveInterop/WaveCallback)
          at NAudio.Wave.WaveCallbackInfo.Connect (NAudio.Wave.WaveInterop+WaveCallback callback) [0x00009] in <554b80148c284b99953f098db496ebd4>:0 
          at NAudio.Wave.WaveOut..ctor (NAudio.Wave.WaveCallbackInfo callbackInfo) [0x0004e] in <554b80148c284b99953f098db496ebd4>:0 
          at NAudio.Wave.WaveOut..ctor () [0x00014] in <554b80148c284b99953f098db496ebd4>:0 
          at MainVideoScript.playSound (System.Int32 deviceNumber) [0x0002e] in <0d2c0b09fee74d5099fd910768d58ea9>:0
```

I am running on `Windows 10`, and the `Target platform=Windows`, so why the platform doesn't support what I am trying to do? What can I change?

Here is the code i am trying to run:

```
        string soundPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, @"clic2.wav");
        waveReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(soundPath);

        var wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
        wave.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        wave.Init(waveReader);
        wave.Play();
```

I am using 2019.2.8f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the `Api compatibility Level` is correct in `Edit` \ `Project Settings` \ `Player`

[image]